# BLDC - Field Oriented Control

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am designing an AGV for which I am in the process of selecting a controller IC for BLDC motor. I read through design considerations document by TI and came to know that FIELD ORIENTED CONTROL will be apt as the AGV will require to output higher torque.
FOC is a new concept to me. From TI's document I was able to comprehend that the stator and rotor magnetic field should be orthogonal to each other. How can this be implemented?

Design consideration: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slvaes1/slvaes1.pdf?ts=1641235641591&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you look at VESC - an open source system able to implement FOC and many other systems. It is used commercially by a number of commercial manufacturers. The very large number of users means that capabilities and problems are very well known and that a large knowledge base is available.

See - The VESC project [here](https://vesc-project.com/) -
They say

- ". Our aim is simply providing the best and most professional open source firmware, user friendly software solutions and hardware for motor control available today. Using VESC hardware and software allows you to set up your device within minutes - not days. Today VESC motor controllers can be found in robots, multicopters, planes, camera gimbals, e-bikes, electric skateboards, RC equipment, industrial applications and many many more."

Google search [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=vesc&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=vesc&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j46i175i199i512l2j0i512l3j0i10i512j0i512j0i10i512j0i512.2194j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - a vast number of links.

---

I have no involvement with VESC.

Answer (score 1):

I have read a lot of application notes, tutorials etc. about the FOC motor control and I can say the best tutorial regarding this topic is on youtube "Teaching Old Motors New Tricks". I suggest you watch these videos to better understand the FOC motor control.